# Natural deduction prove that A$\vee$B, $\neg$ A, $\neg$B $\vdash$ A $\wedge \neg$A

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

I want to prove the following deduction in the natural deduction system:

A$\vee$B, $\neg$ A, $\neg$B $\vdash$ A $\wedge$$\neg$A

Specifically the difficult part:

A$\vee$B, $\neg$ A, $\neg$B $\vdash$ A

How can the result be proven by using the common inference rules?

Comment: $A \land \lnot A$ is a contradiction, denoted $\bot$, which seems to be the aim of your first deduction, and rightly so.  $A$ is merely a proposition that can be true or false,  and does not follow from the premises.  Could you recheck what you posted?

Comment: @amWhy Yes, I want to specifically prove the contradiction, which requires deriving A.

Comment: See my answer, because you can deduce/derive $A$ by using the premise $A\lor B$, **and** the premise $\lnot B$.  I don't know which natural deduction system you know, or are supposed to work with, so I use very common names for inference rules; you can adjust accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have the premise $A\lor B$, as well as the premise $\lnot B$

$\rightarrow (A\lor B) \land (\lnot B)\quad \land$-Introduction

Then

$\big((A\lor B) \land \lnot B\big) \rightarrow A$ by disjunction elimination, also known as disjunction syllogism.

So you can derive $A$ as above. And you're given $\lnot A$. Then through $\land$-Introduction with A, your have $A \land \lnot A$.

$\bot$

I'll let you set up the actual proof with steps numbered, and steps involved, and justifications given

1. Premise
2. Premise
3. Inference from( step #(s)) Justification

$\quad \vdots$

$\quad \vdots$

$A\land \lnot A$

$\bot$

Comment: While I have seen natural deductions where $A \lor B,~\lnot A \vdash B$ is the definition used for Or-Eliminination, that is less common than proof by cases, which is $A \lor B, (A \vdash X), (B \vdash X) \vdash X$.  The proof can be done with either though.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{array} {r|ll}
 (1) & A \lor B            & \text{Given} \\
 (2) & \lnot A             & \text{Given} \\
 (3) & \lnot B             & \text{Given} \\
     &                     & \\
 (4) & \quad \quad A       & \text{Premise} \\
 (5) & \quad \quad \bot    & \text{Contradiction of 2 and 4} \\
     &                     & \\
 (6) & \quad \quad B       & \text{Premise} \\
 (7) & \quad \quad \bot    & \text{Contradiction of 3 and 6} \\
     &                     & \\
 (8) & \bot                & \text{Or Eliminination of 1, 4 to 5, 6 to 7} \\
 (9) & \text{Anything}     & \text{Vaccuous Implication} \\
\end{array}$$